# Creating a varible with a range

Tags: ruby, range

I have a program that attempts to generate open proxies, I will be using this program as a pentesting tool and have recently come across an error:

```
proxygen.rb:134:in `<=': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
        from proxygen.rb:134:in `check_for_amount_of_proxies'
        from proxygen.rb:153:in `<main>'
```

What is happening is I have a variable `@file_size` and a variable `@amount`, the `@amount` variable is used to determine how many possible IP addresses are created and the `@file_size` is used to determine if the program has found the required amount of proxies and saved them to a file.

Source:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/env ruby

require 'colored'
require 'timeout'
require 'net/ping'
require 'proxies-scanner'
require 'etc'

LOGIN = Etc.getlogin
PATH = Dir.pwd

def fatal(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "\n[[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} FATAL]]#{input}".red.bold
end

def notice(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "\n[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} NOTICE]#{input}\n".blue.bold
end

def err(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} ERROR]#{input}".red.bold
end

def info(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} INFO]#{input}".green.bold
end

def success(input)
  t= Time.now
  puts "[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} [SUCCESS]#{input}".green.bold
end

def warn(input)
  t = Time.now
  puts "[#{t.hour}:#{t.min}:#{t.sec} WARNING]#{input}".yellow.bold
end

def self.windows?
  return File.exist? "c:/WINDOWS" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32/
end

def self.linux?
  return File.exist? "/usr" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
end

def self.os
  return :linux if self.linux?
  return :windows if self.windows?
  nil
end

def check_os
  notice("Hello #{LOGIN}, it appears that #{os.capitalize} is your OS, path has been switched to #{PATH}")
end

def check_file
  if File.exist?("proxies.txt")
    File.truncate("proxies.txt", 0)
    notice("File exists in system, resuming process.")
  else 
    notice("File proxies.txt created successfully.")
    File.new("proxies.txt")
  end
end

def choose_proxy_amount
  print "Enter proxy amount: ".yellow.bold
  @amount = gets.chomp.to_i
  notice("Amount is measure in KB")
  case @amount
  when @amount >= 100
    @file_size = 0..2154
  when @amount <= 101
    @file_size = 2166..21618
  else

  end
end

def create_possibles
  notice("Attempting to ping generated IP addresses.")

  ports = %w(80 443 1935 2222 3128 3130 7808 8080 8081 8085 8089 
             8090 8102 8104 8106 8118 8119 8123 8888 8898 9000 
             9090 9797 9999 10000 10052 10053 10059 10088 12345 
             18000 18001 18008 37564 40080 55336 59998
            )

  @amount.times do
    @ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(5) do 
        if Net::Ping::ICMP.new(@ip).ping?# == true
          success("Possible proxies created for IP: #{@ip}")
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") do |proxy|
            ports.each { |port| proxy.puts("#{@ip}:#{port}") }
          end
        else
          err("IP failed to ping: #{@ip}")
        end
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error
      warn("IP timed out: #{@ip}")
      next
    end
  end
end

def check_for_amount_of_proxies
  if File.size("proxies.txt") <= @file_size
    notice("Proxies created, attempting connection")
    system("proxies-scanner -f proxies.txt")
    warn("Truncating file: proxies.txt")
  else
    notice("File doesn't contain enough proxies, restarting IP finding proccess.")
    create_possibles
  end
end

begin
  check_file
  check_os
  choose_proxy_amount
  create_possibles
  check_for_amount_of_proxies
rescue RuntimeError => e
  fatal("This program requires Adminstration access to run, please switch to admin terminal.")
end
```

So the program is failing when it tries to compare the size of the file to the variable `@file_size`. My question being is there a way to create this variable into a range?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It tells you more than "comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)", it should be telling you the line number, which is important for us. Please read "[mcve]". We need a minimal example of the problem code, along with minimal input data that demonstrates the problem, plus your expected output.

Comment: @theTinMan Fixed that should be more specific. The line number isn't vital to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the change, but it doesn't help us run the code to determine where the problem is. If the line number isn't vital, then when mention you're getting an exception?

Comment: @theTinMan I meant it isn't vital because I have a few methods in there to make the puts easier, such as a `warn`, `error` `etc`, I can post the entire program if it would be helpful?

Comment: @theTinMan I have posted the entire source code and have fixed the question, I hope this helps.

Comment: Posting the entire program is not desirable. The idea is, you do the work to isolate the problem and reproduce it in a small, easily digestible program. Anything beyond that wastes our time when helping you and reduces the number of people willing to help you, plus it makes it harder for others to use your question to fix their own problems, which is the goal of SO. Read "[mcve]", http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html as they explain the goal of SO's Q&A and how to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're assigning ranges is fine. Try assigning a range to a variable in IRB or Pry:

```
[3] (pry) main: 0> foo = 1..2
1..2
[4] (pry) main: 0> foo.class
Range < Object
```

You can't use `<= @file_size` if `@file_size` is a range:

```
5 <= 1..6
ArgumentError: bad value for range
```

or

```
5 <= (1..6)
ArgumentError: comparison of Fixnum with Range failed
```

You can use `===` instead:

```
(1..6) === 5
true
```

or:

```
@file_size === File.size("proxies.txt")
```

---

You can't reverse the order of the above. The range MUST be on the left:

```
5 === (1..6)
false
```

There's lots of pages explaining why.

Comment: So if I did `if File.size("proxies.txt") === @file_size` it will work?

Comment: No. It won't. You have to do it like I showed. You should use IRB or Pry to test ideas. That's what we have them.